# Most efficient way to calculate sum of array with many zeroes?

Tags: r

I have a matrix with `n` rows, `m` columns.

I want to apply a function `f(x)` to each element in the matrix, and then sum up the elements *by row* (so the output is a vector).

However, the function value `f(x)` is zero for negative `x`.

So, right now, I am looping over each row, and then applying something like `sum(f(row_i))`.

This works, but how can I do this faster?

Specifically, can I somehow use the fact that I know `f(x)` is zero for negative `x` (and hence doesn't add to the `sum`)? Or can I somehow get rid of the for-looping over the rows as well? I tried `sapply` but it doesn't speed things up.

Comment: Perhaps you could sort the array, and only sum and apply `f` to part of the array where the elements are non-negative.

Comment: Some code would help. If `A` is your matrix, something like `apply(A,1,function(row){sum(sapply(row[row >= 0],f))})` might work. If there are a fair amount of zeros than this should give a substantial speedup.

Comment: `rowSums` perhaps?

Comment: Note also that if your function returns 0 for negative but you are only planning to apply it to positive, than you could rewrite the code for that function to dispense with the sign test since such a test would then be moot.

Comment: It would have been helpful if your post had a reproducible example along with some details of `f` function.

Answer (score 2):

I am not certain this is the **fastest** way, but it will likely be very efficient.

Basically use the vectorized function `rowSums` for summing, buy first convert the matrix into only positive values. If your function `f(x)` is vectorized, you could apply this function to the entire matrix first, and then use `rowSums` as well.

```
n <- 1e6
ncol = 10
dat <- matrix(rnorm(n), ncol= ncol)
system.time(rowSums(ifelse(dat > 0, dat, 0)) #or rowSums(f(dat)))
#output
   user  system elapsed 
   0.02    0.03    0.04
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an apply/sapply approach, with comparisons to a more naive looping approach. The speed-up is by a factor of about 3 (though depends on the percentage of negatives in the matrix)). If the looping that you are doing is even more naive (e.g. with no preallocation) then the speed-up will be greater, but in that case the problem is really with the looping per se rather than the lack of filtering each row. The best approach is to write fully vectorized code if at all possible, and skip looping or sapply entirely. Without more details, it is impossible to say what that would mean in your case. I added how a fully-vectorized version which uses `rowSums()` would work by comparison. As you can see, that is where the real speed-up is:

```
#functions to create a vector of sums where f is applied to the rows of A
#The first method is a naive loop, the second takes advantage of the fact that
#x < 0 imples f(x) == 0

method1 <- function(A,f){
  m <- nrow(A)
  n <- ncol(A)
  v <- rep(0,m)
  for(i in 1:m){
    row <- rep(0,n)
    for(j in 1:n){
      row[j] = f(A[i,j])
    }
    v[i] = sum(row)
  }
  v
}

method2 <- function(A,f){
  apply(A,1,function(row){sum(sapply(row[row >= 0],f))})
}

#for testing:

f <- function(x) max(0,x)^2
g <- function(x) pmax(x,0)^2 #vectorized version of f
A <- matrix(runif(10000,-10,2),nrow = 100)

library(microbenchmark)
print(microbenchmark(method1(A,f),method2(A,f),rowSums(g(A))))
```

Typical output (on my machine):

```
Unit: microseconds
          expr       min         lq       mean     median        uq       max neval
 method1(A, f) 13826.824 14672.9285 16076.5778 15342.0195 16916.631 33829.384   100
 method2(A, f)  5629.886  6009.6550  6687.8325  6247.3185  7117.401 14411.815   100
 rowSums(g(A))   217.566   249.6535   315.7482   271.8685   303.075  2918.966   100
```